# Build Firefox from source code under Mac OS X

Tags: mac, firefox, make, glib

I'm trying to build Firefox from source code under my Macbook pro. I believe I follow all direction on their pages, yet I still stuck on building it up.

I installed all requirement (`mercurial libidl autoconf213 yasm`) via Macport and its under `/opt/local/`. When I tried to run `make -f client.mk`, it gave me error. It seems like it couldn't locate glib 2.0 and libidl. The actual output was like this:

```
checking for libIDL-2.0 >= 0.8.0 glib-2.0 gobject-2.0... checking for glib-config... no
checking for GLIB - version >= 1.2.0... no
*** The glib-config script installed by GLIB could not be found
*** If GLIB was installed in PREFIX, make sure PREFIX/bin is in
*** your path, or set the GLIB_CONFIG environment variable to the
*** full path to glib-config.
checking for libIDL-config... no
checking for libIDL - version >= 0.6.3... no
*** The libIDL-config script installed by libIDL could not be found
*** If libIDL was installed in PREFIX, make sure PREFIX/bin is in
*** your path, or set the LIBIDL_CONFIG environment variable to the
*** full path to libIDL-config.
checking for libIDL-2.0 >= 0.8.0... Package libIDL-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libIDL-2.0.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH   environment variable No package 'libIDL-2.0' found
configure: error: Library requirements (libIDL-2.0 >= 0.8.0) not met; consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if your libraries are in a nonstandard prefix so pkg-config can find them.
```

I Googled for a couple of hours for this one, but still couldn't find the solution for it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone still has this problem, I needed to install the `glib1` port to get Firefox to build; the `glib` port installed glib 2.3 which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing `glib` via MacPorts.

Comment: I did.. and it still gives me error

Comment: @REALFREE: The same error, or another one?